# How to cause template prototype to inherit so all specializations inherit the same class/interface?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

How can i create a template prototype that declares the class to inherit from an interface ?
I want all specializations of that class to inherit from the same interface.

Something like:

```
template <typename T>
class A : public BaseInterface { }

template <>
class A<int> { } //somehow still inherit from the interface "BaseInterface"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. Templates just aren't "classes". They're "templates for classes" (read templates here not as the C++ term, but the English language term). They're skeletons on which actual classes are built. So when you say:

```
template <typename T>
class A : public BaseInterface { }
```

you're not actually declaring a class, you're providing a rule for some classes that will be built. Also, when you specialize a template

```
template <>
class A<int> { } //somehow still inherit from the interface "BaseInterface"
```

you're **explicitly** saying you want it to behave differently for this specialization.

Answer (score 2):

You can not constraint the explicit specializations. But they may be derived from BaseInterface:

```
template <> class A<int>: public BaseInterface {...}
```